# Numpyの配列に、Excelのようなsumif, countif関数はないのですか？

Tags: python, python3, numpy, array

python3配列の計算Excelのようなsumif,countif関数のを探しています。

ご存知の方、ご助言よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば `arr = numpy.array(list(range(10)))` として、`arr[arr>5].sum()` とする様な事でしょうか？

Comment: ご助言の方法で目的を達成できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

条件式を使った添字指定の方法である [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) を使えば

```
# テスト用の numpy array
arr = numpy.array(list(range(10)))
# sumif を出力
print(arr[arr > 5].sum())
# countif を出力
print(numpy.sum(arr > 5))
```

のように書くことができます。

<sub>-- [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38760/%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97excel%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AAsumif-countif%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#comment39027_38760)より。</sub>